# How to create single trigger function that work for multiple RTDB instances?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Let's have 2 databases in RTDB.
Now i want to create a single trigger cloud function (onCreate/onUpdate/onDelete) in node.js that works for both databases.

Comment: Create 2 connexion pool and use them. Where is the challenge?

Comment: Can you share example how to do that?

Comment: You could write a function and then use it in both the triggers like `functions.database.instance('my-app-db-2').ref('/foo/bar').onUpdate(myTriggerHandler)`

Comment: It will work for only 'my-app-db-2'. I want single onUpdate trigger that work for 2 database in RTDB.